# Valox 420 30% glass wear

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, plastic, molding, injection-molding

I am seeking assistance regarding thermoplastic material wear on a new product I am developing.

The attached image is molded out of Valox 420 30% glass. In the left side image, the locking dents are worn off after 2000 rotational cycles, and the right side is a new part. My goal is 4000 cycles on this product.

I am currently reviewing Nylon 46 30% GF this could be up to 20 points higher on the Rockwell HRR scale. I am wondering if anyone has other suggestions for thermoplastics I should review for injection molding?

Thank You for any input[image]
Rob

Comment: Glass reinforced plastics are really abrasive. If it's wearing, how is that part it is wearing against faring? What is that made of? Can you just make the detents wider and/or taller?

Comment: I have reviewed non GF filled materials.

Answer (score 0):

minimization of wear in a glass-loaded molded part usually requires milling a *self-lubricating substance* into the raw material before injection molding, or having the glass-filled part in sliding contact with a teflon part.

Self-lubrication is achieved by mixing oil into the resin stock or by mixing teflon powder into the resin. *Delrin* is a resin which can be made self-lubricating in this way.